# Can't set local storage on mobile, react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, mobile, local-storage

I'm trying to save a JSON Web Token in local storage for authentication purposes. When a user logs in I call the following method.

```
  static authenticateUser(token) {
    try {
      window.localStorage.setItem('token', token);
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error);
    }
  }
```

This works well on desktop but doesn't work at all on mobile. Safari throws a `QuotaExceededError` and Chrome fails silently. Is localStorage not a viable solution for mobile? Should I use cookies instead?

Comment: try only this localStorage.setItem('token', token);

Answer (score 0):

Safari throws `QuotaExceededError` in Private Mode. Just check if you are using provide mode. Also, try to use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` unless you need to store information independent of user' session.

Comment: Good catch on that one. I am ideally trying to store info independent of session.